# Insert April 1, 2017 into MySQL database using JDBC results in March 31, 2017

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connector-j

First I will just note that the server and database are both setup for the EST timezone. I say this because I see lots of comments about issues if the timezones are different, they are the same.

That being said my code:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2017, 04, 01);
java.sql.Date databaseDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myTable (date) VALUES (?)");
preparedStatement.setDate(1, databaseDate);
preparedStatement.execute();
```

However when I do this and then run `SELECT date FROM myTable` the resulting date is March 31, 2017. Again the timezone is the same for the server and database.

How can I save April 1, 2017 into my database?

Comment: Why not inserting the value inside SQL as `2017-04-01`?

Comment: I'm trying to use PreparedStatement for performance because the insert can be used a lot over time. Plus if I was going to do that then I could always do preparedStatement.setString(1, '2017-04-01'); However that defeats the purpose, that's a workaround/hack and doesn't really resolve the issue...

Comment: What is the column type, what connection properties are you using?

Comment: Column type is DATE and I've tried everything possible for connection properties, things like noTimezoneConversionForDateType, useLegacyDatetimeCode, etc. I initially read through the documentation and tried the appropriate options but when all else failed I started to try all kinds of combinations. Nothing seem to affect it. I'm also using ConnectorJ 6